# Hide or filter rows or columns if specific sheets are empty in a google sheet macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to conditionally hide or filter a column if a range is empty. I guess the function "if" does not work since the column is hidden even when the range is not empty.

I will thank if someone check my code.

```
function OcultarSi() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var range = sh.getRange('E2:E24');
    if (range.isBlank()){
        spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
        spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
    }
};
```

Comment: Add more details like what are the values/formulas on E2:E24. Consider to add a screenshot or link to a demo spreadsheet

Comment: @MarioAndres It's pretty close. 1) Lines 3 and 4 have the same effect `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` and `var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];` - you don't need both. 2) Line7: `spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();` "spreadsheet" is not defined, maybe try `sh.getRange('E:E').activate();`. Ditto line 8; try `sh.hideColumns(sh.getActiveRange().getColumn(), sh.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());`.

Comment: Thank you Tedinoz!
No it works, I realized I have changed "spreadsheet" by "ss" but not in all places. Below the code working for any other user who needs a similar one.
.
.
function OcultarSi() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var range = spreadsheet.getRange('E2:E24');
    if (range.isBlank()){
       
 spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();    
 spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  }
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the code working for any user who needs a similar one. . .

```
function OcultarSi(){ 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('E2:E24');
  if (range.isBlank()){ 
    spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(),spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  } 
};
```